# How can I use sed to create this pattern in file

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, centos

I have this file

```
Array ( [0] => ROLE_ADMIN@READ@User [1] => ROLE_ADMIN_DD_USER@READ@User [2] => ROLE_DD_USER@READ@* [3] => ROLE_USER@READ@User [4] => IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY@*@User [5] => *@READ@User [6] => ROLE_ADMIN@form@User [7] => *@form@User [8] =>
```

I want to extract the `ROLE_ADMIN@READ@User` portions and then make them comma separated.

`[ ROLE_ADMIN@READ@User , ROLE_ADMIN@READ@User ]`

I have tried this in `sed`

```
sed -re 's/ ([A-Z_\*]*)@([A-Za-z\*]*)@[a-z\*]*/#/g' role.txt
```

This is half done; I am not sure what to do next.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to capture the values after the `=>`, it would be easier to replace everything else:

```
sed -e 's/.* \[0] => /[ /' -e 's/\[[0-9]*] =>/,/g' -e 's/[, ]*$/]/' role.txt
```

Explanation:

- The first expression replaces the beginning part with `[`
- The second expression replaces all the middle parts with `,`
- The third expression replaces trailing comma and whitespaces with `]`

so that you end up with:

> [ ROLE_ADMIN@READ@User , ROLE_ADMIN_DD_USER@READ@User , ROLE_DD_USER@READ@* , ROLE_USER@READ@User , IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY@*@User , *@READ@User , ROLE_ADMIN@form@User , *@form@User ]

If you want to sort the entries, then I recommend `perl` instead:

```
perl -ne '@u = m/=> *(\S+)/g; print "[ ", join(" , ", sort(@u)), " ]\n"' < role.txt
```

This will give you:

> [ *@READ@User , *@form@User , IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY@*@User , ROLE_ADMIN@READ@User , ROLE_ADMIN@form@User , ROLE_ADMIN_DD_USER@READ@User , ROLE_DD_USER@READ@* , ROLE_USER@READ@User ]

Comment: thanks for that , can we sort them also or we need to use awk for that

Comment: Nope, this technique is not suitable for sorting. I recommend `perl` for that, see my updated answer.